# Php mySQL loop within loop from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

So, I have 2 tables and I want to try and do an iterative loop within a loop...

Table one is a list of Football Games
Table 2 is a list of The channels these are on.

Table 1 has an auto increment ID for each game & then table two has a column which relates to this...

Heres an example of table 1

```html
 
id | title                 | highlight |  date       |  time   | logo | background
1  | Sevilla vs Celta Vigo | No        |  2017-04-28 |  18:00:00 | La Liga | "background": "url"
```

and here of table 2

```html
 
id | name
1  | Sports Pick 2
1  | Sports Pick 2 HD
1  | Sports Pick UHD
```

Now what I am wanting to do is display a loop of table 1, however for each value, also loop the channels where the ID matches in table 2

This is the code I have written so far

```html
<?php

 echo "<pre>{
 \"fixtures\": [<pre>";


    //connect to mysql db
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","DATABASEUSERHERE","DATABASEPASSWORDHERE") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    //connect to the employee database
    mysql_select_db("DATABASENAMEHERE", $con);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM fixture_list";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '{
   "title": "'.$row[title].'",
   "highlight": "'.$row[highlight].'",
   "date": "'.$row[date].'",
   "time": "'.$row[time].'",
   "logo": "'.$row[logo].'",'.$row[background].'
   ';
  echo '"channels": [
    { "name": "Sports Pick 2" },
    { "name": "Sky Sports 2" }
   ]
  },';
 }
 
 echo "
 ]
}";


?>
```

so this works well, but i've only got the 1st loop running here and am struggling to see how or where I'd pop the second loop and how i'd do a foreach or something like that to get the relevant values in the second loop...

Here is a copy of the desired output I am looking for

```html
{
 "fixtures": [
{
   "title": "Sevilla vs Celta Vigo",
   "highlight": "No",
   "date": "2017-04-28",
   "time": "18:00:00",
   "logo": "La Liga",
   "background": "URL",
   "channels": [
    { "name": "Sports Pick 2" },
    { "name": "Sports Pick 2 HD" },
    { "name": "Sports Pick UHD" }
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

I'm looking forward to some guidance on this and seeing how this works out... thanks in anticipation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli` as `msql` has been deprecated

```
<?php

echo "<pre>{
    \"fixtures\": [<pre>";


//connect to mysql db
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","000000");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
//connect to the employee database
mysqli_select_db($con, 'ng_app');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM fixture_list";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$json = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json .= '{
            "title": "'.$row['title'].'",
            "highlight": "'.$row['highlight'].'",
            "date": "'.$row['date'].'",
            "time": "'.$row['time'].'",
            "logo": "'.$row['logo'].'",
            "background" : "' . $row['background'] . '",
            ';
    $json .= '"channels": [
                ' . getChannels($row['id'], $con) . '
            ]
        },';
}
echo rtrim($json, ',');
echo "
    ]
}";


function getChannels($fixture_id, $con) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `channels` WHERE `id` = $fixture_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $data = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data .= '{"name": "' . $row['name'] .'"},';
    }
    return rtrim($data, ',');
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
{
"fixtures": [{
  "title": "Sevilla vs Celta Vigo",
  "highlight": "No",
  "date": "2017-04-28 00:00:00",
  "time": "18:00:00",
  "logo": "La Liga",
  "background": "URL",
  "channels": [{
    "name": "Sports Pick 2"
  }, {
    "name": "Sports Pick 2 HD"
  }, {
    "name": "Sports Pick UHD"
   }]
 }]
}
```

Comment: this is almost spot on... except I need there to be a comma betweet each of the fixtures but not after the last one... any thoughts>

Comment: @HenryAspden see my updated answer, save the results in a variable then use `rtrim` to remove the trailing comma.

Answer (score 1):

I would select both tables in two queries and do the assignments in PHP.

Since I don't know the `mysql_*` functions - Here is a mysqli solution:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'DATABASEUSERHERE', 'DATABASEPASSWORDHERE', 'DATABASENAMEHERE');

$data = [];
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM fixture_list");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    unset($row['id']);
    $row['channels'] = [];
    $data[$id] = $row;
}

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM channels");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['id']]['channels'][] = ['name' => $row['name']];
}
```

You can now loop throug the `$data` array and print the values. Or just use `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Or

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```